# Rashi's apparent internal confusion over יתרו/רְעוּאֵל

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, rashi, midrash, yisro--the-man

Per Bamidbar 10:29 (see below), חֹבָב בֶּן רְעוּאֵל was the father-in-law of מֹשֶׁה.  There, רש"י asks why רְעוּאֵל is referred to in [Shemoth 2:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9863/showrashi/true) as the "father" of בנות יתרו, and he answers that they called their grandfather, "father." But in [Shemoth 18:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9879/showrashi/true) רש"י lists רְעוּאֵל as one of the seven names of יתרו and states that only *some* say the aforementioned answer about רְעוּאֵל being the grandfather.

What is the deal with יתרו/רְעוּאֵל? Does רש"י give any insight anywhere else? Does anyone else address this? I know there is a citation within the commentary for ספרי. Is there an explanation there (Chabad.org says it's in Beha’alothecha 10:29, the first location in this question)?

כט. וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה לְחֹבָב בֶּן רְעוּאֵל הַמִּדְיָנִי חֹתֵן מֹשֶׁה נֹסְעִים אֲנַחְנוּ אֶל הַמָּקוֹם...‏
חובב: הוא יתרו, שנאמר (שופטים ד, יא) מבני חובב חותן משה, ומה תלמוד לומר (שמות ב, יח) ותבאנה אל רעואל אביהן, מלמד שהתינוקות קורין לאבי אביהן אבא. ושמות הרבה [ושני שמות] היו לו יתר על שם שיתר פרשה אחת בתורה. חובב על שחבב את התורה וכו

(Above quotations copied/pasted from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9938/showrashi/true).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mizrachi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11834&st=&pgnum=210), on the Rashi to Shemos 18:1, seems to assume that according to the midrashic opinion that Yisro had seven names, which included both Chovav and R'uel, both Yisro and his father had the name R'uel.

Comment: +1 for finding that, but two things: First, why, then, is there a need for Rashi (or "Yesh Omerim") to say that the daughters called their grandfather "father"? Second, it's hard to read the text, but I think he might be saying that he doesn't think along the lines of that interpretation (that they both had the same name). Maybe I'm just struggling with the print/scan quality.

Comment: @SethJ, Rashi is citing conflicting midrashim, which as Mizrachi points out, is not uncommon.

Comment: OK; I just expanded my question above.

Comment: He seems to fully endorse the Yesh Omerim, though.

Comment: @SethJ, I'm not sure what you're saying exactly, but who can blame 
Rashi for endorsing the *yesh om'rim*? If I were a p'shat commentator, I would do the same, as that opinion makes more contextual sense. The better question is why Rashi finds the need to bring the "seven names" midrash. But I would assume he brings it just to show that Chovav = Yisro.

Comment: @SethJ, The Mizrachi there seems to be bothered by the fact that Rashi brought the "seven names" midrash and then the other midrashic opinion that R'uel was actually not one of Yisro's names, but he didn't bring the *other* midrashic opinions (which apparently exist) that several of the other names listed also did not belong to Yisro. Why is Rashi discriminating between midrashim that argue with the original "seven names" midrash?

Comment: Jake, to [your question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13951/rashis-apparent-internal-confusion-over#comment24970_13952) I thought exactly what you articulate: "Why is Rashi even bringing that Midrash? Oh, right, "Hovav=Yithro"; I guess he can't pick it apart." But, then, he explains _a couple_ of the names and then stops! Does the Midrash stop there, too? And to your second point, you're only further exacerbating and strengthening my question. (This is not a knock against your answer, btw. You still get my +1. It's just that there are so many questions that come up...)

Comment: I'm not sure there's much more to add, but just in case, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2405/discussion-between-seth-j-and-jake) rather than in the comments.